# Button link not going anywhere

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a button in a Modal take you to a new page but It wont change page.

Here is a pastebin for the whole lot - http://pastebin.com/2TBgYpbv

but the problem is this code here -

```
<button href="manager.php?staffname=<?php echo"$staffname";?>&ban=true" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
```

Please explain why it's not redirecting

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a live preview.

Comment: http://universal-craft.com/editstaff.php?staffname=michaelwilson94#top Press ban and then Confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the button to an anchor. Keep the css classes etc. Or, add a button click handler to change window.location. I suggest the first option.

The button tag does not have an href attribute. Read more about button on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: What else could I use instead of href?

Comment: Why does it have to be a button? You could wrap it in a form and change the button type to submit. Be sure to set the action of the form and target.

Comment: Changing it to an Anchor like you said worked. Thank you very much :)